# AVR unable to enter programming mode

Tags: microcontroller, avr, oscillator, crystal, fuse-bits

I have an ATMega88PB on a PCB which won't enter programming mode after changing the fuse settings to EXTFSXTAL_16KCK_14CK_0MS. Prior to this, the AVRISP MkII was able to communicate with the microcontroller (I've since switched to an Atmel ICE which still isn't able to communicate).
[image: Atmel Studio error]

In case there are any doubts that I have changed other fuse settings incorrectly, here is a screenshot of the fuses prior to programming.
[image: Fuse settings]

I find this confusing because the oscillator appears to be running fine - if I had programmed the incorrect fuse setting (e.g. ext clk) then I would expect the oscillator to be disabled to save power. As you can see this isn't the case, with the oscillator running just slightly under 20MHz.

XTAL2 waveform:
[image: XTAL2 Waveform]

XTAL1 waveform:
[image: XTAL1 Waveform]

Here is the schematic for the oscillator circuit:
[image: Schematic]

I've tried programming the device at every available speed and still haven't had any luck. I also tried feeding in a clock signal from a working AVR's CLK0 pin unsuccessfully, and have tried 18pF load capacitors in place of the 33pF indicated in the schematic.

What else can I try to get this microcontroller running again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your low fuse register is 0xD7. That equals 0b1101 0111 in binary.

Looking at the data sheet the lower 4 bits are responsible for the clock. This correlates to

CKSEL3 = 0, CKSEL2 = 1, CKSEL1 = 1, CKSEL0 = 1.

From the data sheet this is not a valid setting, but it may be set to a low frequency crystal. The two similar valid settings are 0b0100 and 0b0101, they are both for a low frequency oscillator. Try replacing the 20MHz crystal with a 32.768kHz crystal.

An expected frequency and actual frequency mismatch may result in the processor not starting.

If that does not work, you may have to use parallel programming to recover the chip. Parallel programming does not require a working crystal and provides a clock externally.

Here is a screen capture of the data sheet.
[image]

Comment: I'm not at a computer at the moment so I can't check, but is it possible that the fuse register shown by atmel studio is the old fuse settings it has detected prior to writing the new fuse? (In the screenshot, SUT_CKSEL has been changed but not yet written).

Comment: Page 27 of the datasheet says CKSEL3...0 = 0111 - 0110 corresponds to full swing crystal oscillator so I'm not sure why you think it's an invalid setting.

Further, SUT1...0 and CKSEL0 = 011 corresponds to crystal oscillator, BOD enabled. (startup time 16k CK, +19CK from reset) and finally CKDIV8 = 1 means clock division is disabled.

These are the fuses I have intended to program so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @bhillam I'm not sure what data sheet your working from, where did you get it? I got this data sheet from Atmels web site. Pictured is page 30. The oscillator setting 0111 is not listed.

Comment: I appear to have a preliminary datasheet. http://imgur.com/ID8x0TR not that it should matter since Atmel Studio should have the correct fuse settings (I didn't type in the hex field, I chose them in the GUI).

Comment: @bhillam So what is exactly in the HEX fields? Because your screen capture shows 16kCK_14CK_0MS which is not a setting listed in the data sheet.

Comment: I have no way of finding out what the actual fuse bits are now since the programmer won't communicate with the avr. When I can get my hands on a 32 kHz crystal I'll try check with that.

Comment: I replaced the 20MHz crystal with a 32.768kHz crystal and now the oscillator doesn't start up at all - before it was oscillating, but not responding to the programmer.

Comment: @bhillam Then parallel programming is the only way left to recover the chip.

Comment: I ended up getting the chip programming again by injecting an external 1MHz clock to the XTAL1/TOSC1 pin (my mistake before was leaving the crystal connected when doing so). The fuses as read by the programmer now are ex:F9, hi:DF, lo:77, so I'm not sure where the software got the previous fuse bits from.

This appears to be the full swing crystal oscillator as expected, so I'm not sure why there was a problem. The crystal was oscillating at 20MHz but was _not_ full swing (it only reached about 2V pk-pk) so my question now is - why can't the oscillator reach the rails? (0-5V)?

Comment: For what it's worth, the full swing crystal oscillator option was removed from rev. 42176E (October 2015) of the ATMega48/88/168PB datasheet (no explanation given). Furthermore the datasheet doesn't seem to indicate that operation above 16MHz is supported for low power crystal oscillator (the only high speed oscillator option). Finally, AtmelStudio doesn't appear to narrow the fuse options based on the selected device - allowing completely meaningless fuses to be programmed.